# PHP, Extract function call name with regex

Tags: php, regex

```
$textvar = "Text(foo): " . func1("foo (bar)") . func2 ($some_arg);
```

What regex can I use to extract the above function names to verify
the existance of these functions?

Comment: Do you mean `Text` in Text(foo)?

Comment: Or do you mean `foo` in `foo (bar)`?

Comment: I'd assume he means `func1(` and `func2(` and wants `Text(` and `foo(` ignored because they appear in strings. If so, a regex will be insufficient. See token_get_all.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
<? if(function_exists($function_name)) {
    //do something; 
}
?>
```